# Trying to join three tables where master table does not have a relation directly with child table

Tags: mysql, database

My Book table

```
customerid   |   timeslotid  |   stype

 1                  1             1
 1                  2             2
 3                  2             3
 3                  1             4
```

Timetable

```
timeslotsid   |   dayslotid  |  

 1                  1             
 1                  2             
 2                  4             
 3                  1
```

Days

```
 dayslotsid     |      day   |  

     1                  Sun             
     2                  Mon             
     3                  Tue             
     4                  Wed
```

I need to relate Book table with Days table for example
Select day,stype but I couldnt do it with inner join

I tried
select customerid,timeslotid from Book B1 inner join Timetable T1 on T1.timeslotid=B1.timeslotid inner join Days D1 on D1.dayslotsid=B1.timeslotid;

I didnt work and I am out of clue so please help

Comment: In your Timetable you have id 1 repeated it is by mistake or purposeful

Comment: @ClementAmarnath PurposefullI didnt enter the whole table its pretty huge

Comment: I need Book table to connect to Days table through Timetable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT B1.customerid, B1.stype, D1.day
FROM Book B1
INNER JOIN Timetable T1 on T1.timeslotid=B1.timeslotid
INNER JOIN Days D1 on D1.dayslotsid=T1.dayslotid;
```

Starting from your query, I changed the join condition on D1 from `D1.dayslotsid=B1.timeslotid` to `D1.dayslotsid=T1.dayslotid` and added `B1.stype` to the field selection based on your example.

Comment: I havent put the entire table but the content is similar I get this error when tried your way 
Column 'dayslotsid' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: See how I prefixed each field by its table alias, e.g. B1, D1 or T1?  Did you add a field to the select list without indicating its table?

Comment: Ahhh yes added prefix .. Now working may I know the use of prefixing?

Comment: Multiple tables in a query may have columns by the same name, and a table may be joined into a query multiple times.  Each use of a table in a query can be named so that columns can be accurately referenced.  If you don't join a table multiple times, you can leave out the alias and use the original table name to distinguish columns with the same name.